# Why is orig_eax provided in addition to eax?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cpu-registers

Why is the `orig_eax` member included in `sys/user.h`'s `struct user_regs_struct`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Because it was in `struct pt_regs`, which is .... http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/arch/x86/include/asm/user_32.h#L77

```
 73  * is still the layout used by user mode (the new
 74  * pt_regs doesn't have all registers as the kernel
 75  * doesn't use the extra segment registers)
```

So, a lot of user-space utilities expect an `orig_eax` field here, so it is included in `user_regs_struct` too (to be compatible with older debuggers and `ptrace`rs)

Next question is "Why is the `orig_eax` member included in `struct pt_regs`?".

It was added in linux 0.95 http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-old+v0.95/include/sys/ptrace.h#L44.
I suggest this was done after some other unix with `pt_regs` struct. Comment in 0.95 says

```
  29 * this struct defines the way the registers are stored on the 
  30 * stack during a system call.
```

So, the place of `orig_eax` is defined by syscall interface. Here it is http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-old+v0.95/kernel/sys_call.s

```
  17 * Stack layout in 'ret_from_system_call':
  18 *      ptrace needs to have all regs on the stack.
  19 *      if the order here is changed, it needs to be 
  20 *      updated in fork.c:copy_process, signal.c:do_signal,
  21 *      ptrace.c ptrace.h
  22 *
  23 *       0(%esp) - %ebx
 ...
  29 *      18(%esp) - %eax
 ...
  34 *      2C(%esp) - orig_eax
```

Why do we need to save old `eax` twice? Because `eax` will be used for the return value of syscall (same file, a bit below):

```
  96_system_call:
  97        cld
  98        pushl %eax              # save orig_eax
  99        push %gs
...
 102        push %ds
 103        pushl %eax              # save eax.  The return value will be put here.
 104        pushl %ebp
...
 117        call _sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
```

Ptrace needs to be able to read both all registers state before syscall and the return value of syscall; but the return value is written to `%eax`. Then original `eax`, used before syscall will be lost. To save it, there is a `orig_eax` field.

UPDATE: Thanks to R.. and great LXR, I did a full search of `orig_eax` in linux 0.95.

It is used not only in ptrace, but also in [do_signal](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-old+v0.95/kernel/signal.c#L152) when restarting a syscall (if there is a syscall, ended with `ERESTARTSYS`)

```
 158                        *(&eax) = orig_eax;
```

UPDATE2: Linus [said](http://lkml.org/lkml/2006/8/29/350) something interesting about it:

> It's important that ORIG_EAX be set to some value that is *not* a 
>   valid system call number, so that the system call restart logic (see the 
>   signal handling code) doesn't trigger.

UPDATE3: `ptrace`r app (debugger) can change `orig_eax` to change system call number to be called:  http://lkml.org/lkml/1999/10/30/82 (in some versions of kernel, is was EIO to change in ptrace an ORIG_EAX)

Comment: cracking answer to a (seemingly) flimsy question!

Comment: I figured it was related to syscalls (and possibly syscall restarting). +1 for tracking down the details!

Comment: note, that recent kernels renamed field to orig_ax - if you want to do a LXR search, do both orig_eax and orig_ax.

Comment: Why would it need orig_eax anyway? Why would it matter what system call it is after the appropriate one was invoked? As I understand, the return value of system call is written to the stack, where late we pop it and save it in eax. And orig_eax is there just to make sure we do not loose the sys call invoked. My other question, why is the return value written on stack and not immediately to eax?