# Ptrace without exec does not work?

Tags: linux, exec, ptrace

I would like to trace system calls. Many examples on how to do this are
available on the web. They all do fork/ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)/exec. When
I don't do the exec in the child then I don't see the system calls executed
by the child in the parent. Any idea why?

I am using this kernel:

Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-49-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:28:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My final goal is to use clone in combination with ptrace so that the tracer and
the tracee can run in the same memory space.

Comment: This is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092828/2319122 but it's not clear that this question is a duplicate.